# Как удалить все символы после определенного символа в элементе списка Python?

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени суток! Я не силен в питоне, и во время парсинга с помощью BeautifulSoup столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть список с температурой на каждый день недели, примерно такой:
['4°0°36', '4°0°72', '3°-1°36', '3°0°36', '10°2°108', '5°4°108', '10°3°108']. Как можно заметить, в каждом элементе списка присутствуют лишние символы.
Мне нужен способ удалить все символы в каждом элементе списка после последнего знака "°", то есть список будет примерно такой:
['4°0°', '4°0°', '3°-1°', '3°0°', '10°2°', '5°4°', '10°3°'].
Буду признателен любой вашей помощи!

Comment: `[x.rsplit('°',1)[0]+'°' for x in ['4°0°36', '4°0°72', '3°-1°36', '3°0°36', '10°2°108', '5°4°108', '10°3°108']]`

Comment: Благодарю! Все сработало